# Separating individual graphs in a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, plot

I have an N by 2 numpy array consisting of different points on a plot, where the first column corresponds to the x-value and the second corresponds to the y-value. By plotting this data, it is clear that the data actually consists of distinct lines, as shown here [image].

My goal is to separate the full array into sub-arrays, each representing one of the lines shown in the picture. I can separate the individual lines according to their relative height, as shown here
[image]

but this doesn't do exactly what I want, since there are places where the lines intersect. I've been trying to come up with suitable algorithms for dealing with this, but none have been very robust. Are there any functions or packages that are able to separate the distinct lines in a mostly-intelligent way?

EDIT: I have included two examples of the data I'm referring to [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1qaxWxK5k3gahj337rFYNgl5qAbuXlmUYDj3nfF1P3n4/edit?usp=sharing) and [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1p6Mw1S48cYEyJ9gEtsIf3w7C6gXvkIR2JyNv5f3y7IE/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: Can you provide your sample data? Also: You really can not control how the original array is created?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I've uploaded two cases of sample data. I can control how the original array is created in that I can get it to look like the second of the two pictures, but I'm struggling to come up with an algorithm that will separate them into reasonably-looking lines. Of course, I'm not asking anyone to spend the time of writing their own algorithm (unless they want to :P), my question was more if any program like this already exists.

Comment: Did you find a solution? If not I want to look deeper into this question tonight - this is very interesting.

Comment: Nope, I haven't found one yet. There is one ambiguity that I hadn't thought of - if two lines meet at a point where both of their slopes are zero (for example, x^2 and -x^2), there isn't an unambiguous way to pick the "correct" path through the intersection. So the question is ill-posed in certain situations, but I suppose there are still a lot of cases where it's a reasonable question to ask.